# Access variable in parent scope when using module pattern

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering what is the best way to access the `obj` variable in this example:

```
function Module() {


  $('foo').on('click', function() {
    if (obj.test === true) {
      // do something
    }
  })


  return {
     setObj: function(obj) {
       // what should I do
     }
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way to access `obj` in the click handler. I'm looking for the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `obj` where it is in scope to both functions:

```
function Module() {

  var obj;

  $('foo').on('click', function() {
    if (obj.test === true) {
      // do something
    }
  })


  return {
    setObj: function(_obj) {
      obj = _obj;
    }
  }
}
```

If Module is used as a constructor (with `new`), you could also us this:

```
function Module() {

  var self = this;

  $('foo').on('click', function() {
    if (self.obj.test === true) {
      // do something
    }
  })

}

Module.prototype.setObj = function ( obj ) {
    this.obj = obj;
};
```

Or with ES6:

```
function Module() {

  $('foo').on('click', _ => {
    if (this.obj.test === true) {
      // do something
    }
  })

}

Module.prototype.setObj = function ( obj ) {
    this.obj = obj;
};
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but it clearly seems to be the best solution

Comment: @julesbou Is there a specific reason why you were trying to avoid that? I added a couple of alternatives.

Comment: you're awesome, but I prefer functional style and avoid using `this` if possible.